# Ask Permissions on a button or icon with tool tip

Tags: buttons, guidelines, actions

> [image]

I looking a link for icon and text for request access. Please share how i can make this UI better.
Should i use just a simple button with text "Ask Permissions" or simply a lock icon with tooltip "Ask Permissions"?

Is there is any better way of putting this UI.

Comment: A screenshot of the existing interface/prototype showing the area you're talking about would be helpful.

Comment: what plateform are you using?

Comment: @gpgpgp Added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lock icon adds value here, as it's a clearly understood convention for protected pages, so I would keep it. As for tooltip -- that should be added as a supplement to the text, but not replacement.

Comment: Just a little tip: Alt + 0151 (—) instead of -- :P